# Calling bash getopts from a function fails the 2nd time

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I'm trying to parse arguments passed to a bash `function` using `getopts` inside that function. It works when the function is called for the first time but fails on all subsequent calls.

Here is a simple test case:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getopt_test {
    PARAMS=""
    while getopts "a:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            a)
                PARAMS="${PARAMS} $OPTARG"
                ;;
        esac
    done
    echo "PARAMS => $PARAMS"
}

getopt_test -a call_1
getopt_test -a call_2
```

The output of the  script is this:

```
~$ ./tst.sh
PARAMS =>  call_1
PARAMS =>               <--- missing 'call_2'
~$
```

I guess `getopts` should somehow be reset before calling it for the second time but I can't really figure out how. Any ideas?

Comment: This is duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048326/getopts-wont-call-twice-in-a-row

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that `getopts` keeps the pointer in `$OPTIND` and therefore the trick is to add `local OPTIND` or `OPTIND=1` to the beginning of the `getopt_test` function.

Thanks to @sivann for providing the link to [getopts won't call twice in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048326/2344631) on StackOverflow